# Import normal javascript file in reactjs component but event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I import some files like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import './lazysizes.min.js';
import './bootstrap.min.js';
import './lazyyoutube.js'; // my custome code
```

In lazyyoutube.js, I write event to load thumbnail images but I can not work:

```
(function () {
  console.log(456)
  const youtube = document.querySelectorAll('.youtube');
  for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {
    var source = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + youtube[i].id + '/sddefault.jpg';
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = source;
    image.addEventListener('load', function () {
      youtube[i].appendChild(image);
    }(i));

    youtube[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
      iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');
      iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'autoplay');
      iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + this.id + '?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1');
      this.innerHTML = '';
      this.appendChild(iframe);
    });
  };
})();
```

**But why bootstrap.min.js can work here and embbed with jquery.min.js in normal html file? And how do I do the same thing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React took time to initially load and render the html, so your code maybe doesn't work because it is immediately invoked.

The workaround for this, you can use React lifecycle method `componentDidMount` to wait for component to be actually mounted and so you can perform your custom logic inside `componentDidMount`

the code for that would be

```js
import React from 'react';

class SomeClass extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
  const youtube = document.querySelectorAll('.youtube');
  for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {
    var source = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + youtube[i].id + '/sddefault.jpg';
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = source;
    image.addEventListener('load', function () {
      youtube[i].appendChild(image);
    }(i));

    youtube[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
      iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');
      iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'autoplay');
      iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + this.id + '?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1');
      this.innerHTML = '';
      this.appendChild(iframe);
    });
  };
}

// ... other
}
```

Comment: I see but why do others library work? They are not react component.

Comment: i don't know for exact why, but i think that other library actually tries to wait for the whole dom to be loaded and rendered first. that's another way to do this, but i recommend to just use `componentDidMount` since you are using react

Comment: thanks but I want to write this for my special purpose so I want to know what reason is, rather than how to quickly finish my task

Comment: well, in that case, it was because other libs like bootstrap is bundled by a module bundler, they take care of how of to do many things, including waiting for dom to load and such, you may want to take a look at [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/lets-learn-how-module-bundlers-work-and-then-write-one-ourselves-b2e3fe6c88ae/#:~:text=A%20module%20bundler%20is%20a,or%20one%20of%20many%20others) article on how they work, if you're curious about it